# Android: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

I receive this error;

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] dat=content://media/external/audio/media }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2007)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1673)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4586)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:712)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4544)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:693)
        at com.emresaritas.basicmediaplayer.MainActivity.openMedia(MainActivity.java:65)
        at com.emresaritas.basicmediaplayer.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:59)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Code;

```
public void openMedia(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_MEDIA);
}
```

Manifest;

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.BasicMediaPlayer">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BasicMediaPlayer.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

I've tried to change intent actions and activity structure but couldn't solve my problem. I'm trying to use intent to let user select a file from the storage.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I still don't know why i was getting this error but i done this;

1. Adding `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />` line to intent-filter.
2. I was using Android TV emulator (API 28) and changed that to API Tiramisu.

Probably it was some android api level problem.

Comment: "I'm trying to develop the application for TV, maybe that's why I'm encountering this error" -- if you really are intending for this code to run on an Android TV device, I would expect few actual devices to support that `Intent` action.